# How to move a domain name from another server to Plesk?

Tags: domains, server, plesk

I'm having a domain which is hosted in dedicated server, and i brought another server with Plesk support, I created the same domain name on the Plesk and now I need transfer my domain name from older to Plesk,

How is it possible?

Comment: When you say move domain, do you mean the domain records are on the old server and you need to move them to the new server, or are they hosted on a different one?

Answer (score 2):

All you should need to do is change the nameservers for the domain name to point to your new server. This may require changing the nameservers completely or just changing the A records for the domain name. If you set the domain name up properly on the new server through Plesk then once the DNS change has propagated you should be able to see the site on your new server.

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate the account/domain from one server to another. 
Plesk has good materiel on this

http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP12/12.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-win-cli/index.htm?fileName=73529.htm

> migrate --migrate-customer customer1,customer2 -host 
>   192.168.1.100 -password mypassword